# maven integration-tests does not run all tests specified in UnitTest class

Tags: maven

maven integration-tests does not run all tests specified in UnitTest class. The UnitClass has around 800 tests listed but it only runs 250, no exception occurs.

What setting needs to be done in pom.xml so that it can be ensured that all the tests would run.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>base</groupId>
    <artifactId>master</artifactId>
    <version>10.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath/>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>tests</artifactId>
  <version>10.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>eclipse-test-plugin</packaging>
  <properties>
    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
    <bundle.test.suite>${project.artifactId}</bundle.test.suite>
    <bundle.test.class>Unit</bundle.test.class>
    <bundle.test.vmargs.extra/>

  </properties>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>integration-tests</id>
      <properties>
        <skipTests>false</skipTests>
        <bundle.test.class>NEWUNIT</bundle.test.class>
        <surefire.timeout>4500</surefire.timeout>

      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tychoVersion}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <forkMode>always</forkMode>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: How is named example executed and not executed test?

Comment: Well in my case, maven stops running the tests after certain limit and publishes the build as successful.

Comment: Added the pom.xml code that I am using

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Maven runs only test classes which match default patterns, because `includes` configuration parameter is not specified for tycho-surefire-plugin.

[includes](http://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-surefire/tycho-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes)

> List of patterns (separated by commas) used to specify the tests that should be included in testing. When not specified and whent the test parameter is not specified, the default includes will be **/Test*.java **/*Test.java **/*TestCase.java

Comment: All the test which are in my Unit file have 'Test'  appended at the end. SO it should run, how can it just stop in middle and say build is successful.

Comment: According to my hypothesis, it does not stop in the middle, it just does not run some tests.

Comment: Try to set `<includes>**/*.java</includes>` and see if it makes a difference. And what is the command you use to run tests? Is it something like `mvn clean test -Pintegration-tests`?

Comment: I am running mvn -Pintegration-tests verify